# Switching bindings for SLF4J as a runtime scoped dependency in Maven

Tags: maven, slf4j

Think to [*Simple Logging Facade (SLF4J)*](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) for Java. As a background, it provides an API by means of a simple *facade pattern* in a way that the underlying logging backend is determined at runtime by adding the desired binding to the classpath. It may be the standard *java.util.logging*, *log4j*, *logback* or *tinylog*.

The neat separation of the client application from the logging backend reduces the coupling between the specific application and any particular logging framework. This can make it easier to integrate a newly implemented client with existing code of other projects that have already made a choice of logging backend.

So considering the logging API *SLF4J*, for compilation you need only the *slf4j-api* and you shall avoid including any specific binding like *slf4j-log4j12* as a *compile* dependency.

As result, *slf4j-log4j12* is a good candidate for being a *runtime* scoped dependency instead of a *compile* dependency, because this will allow you to switch among *slf4j bindings* at runtime without having to recompile the application.

### Question: where to set the switching among logging frameworks bindings at runtime in a Maven project? Any example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of SLF4J

Even though the documentation talks about changing the logging back-end at runtime, SLF4J allows to switch logging back-ends at **build time** but not at runtime.

Comment: Deployment time is probably a more accurate description of when the logging back-end is set: after build time (as you can swap out the logging back-end without modifying your project jar) but before runtime (once the VM is running, you’re stuck with whatever back-end you have at that point).